# How to aggregate data in a sequence using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

[image: Source]

and would like to query it to achieve this result:

[image: Destination]

I'm completely lost how to even start such query. Was looking at UNPIVOT but not even sure how I would apply it here for that purpose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `LEAD/LAG` maybe? There's many examples of this online

Comment: This isn't aggregation. This uses the next/previous value in an ordered result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't aggregation. This uses the next/previous value in an ordered result set. You can use the [Lead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or `Lag` analytic functions for this.

You can use `LEAD(Start) Over (ORDER BY Start)` to get `Stop`, `LEAD(Coordinates) Over (ORDER BY Start)` to get the previous coordinate and concatenate it to the current one, eg :

```
SELECT
    Start,
    LEAD(Coordinates) Over (ORDER BY Start) As STOP,
    CONCAT_WS(',',LEAD(Coordinates) Over (ORDER BY Start),Coordinates) 
        AS COORDINATES
From ThatTable
```

`LEAD` will return `NULL` if there's no value to display, unless a default is specified. This means the last `STOP` value will be NULL. The question doesn't specify what should be displayed in the last row.

**PS**

If you provided the actual `CREATE TABLE` statement and sample data, it would be possible to create a query that actually reproduces what you want. Images can't be copied and queried

Comment: Big thanks Panagiotis!  Very much appreciated! I suppose you've answered my question perfectly as it gave me a idea, solution to follow.  I didn't even have had an idea how to go about what I'm after!

Comment: I'll use you suggestion in PS next time round! 
Thanks again!